# Plotting two lines with seaborn using lineplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to plot two lines on the Y axis with `sns.lineplot` with a dataframe that follows this structure:

```
Datestamp       y_1     y_2
2020-08-01      0       1
2020-08-02      1       2
2020-08-03      3       1
2020-08-04      5       1
```

In the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) it uses `hue` which I do not have in my dataFrame, when I run two lines one below the other like so:

```
sns.lineplot(x = 'Datestamp', y = 'y_1', data=df)
sns.lineplot(x = 'Datestamp', y = 'y_2', data=df)
```

And add a random `hue` parameter I am not sure if the line `hues` are the same for different lines and the `hue` legend gets duplicated.

How can I get a simple two-line chart using seaborn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you current structure you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sns.lineplot(x = 'Datestamp', y = 'y_1', data=df, color='r', lw=3)
sns.lineplot(x = 'Datestamp', y = 'y_2', data=df, color='g', lw=3)
plt.legend(labels=['x_1','y_1'], facecolor='white')
```